# Why is this return statement needed?

Tags: java, if-statement, return

This is a method from the book "Absolute Java." I don't understand why the last else statement needs a return value of 0. The author's comment is "Needed to keep the compiler happy". And is there a reason the return value is 0, or could it be any integer?

```
public int getMonth( )
{
    if (month.equals("January"))
        return 1;
    else if (month.equals("February"))
        return 2;
    else if (month.equalsIgnoreCase("March"))
        return 3;
    else if (month.equalsIgnoreCase("April"))
        return 4;
    else if (month.equalsIgnoreCase("May"))
        return 5;
    else if (month.equals("June"))
        return 6;
    else if (month.equalsIgnoreCase("July"))
        return 7;
    else if (month.equalsIgnoreCase("August"))
        return 8;
    else if (month.equalsIgnoreCase("September"))
        return 9;
    else if (month.equalsIgnoreCase("October"))
        return 10;
    else if (month.equals("November"))
        return 11;
    else if (month.equals("December"))
        return 12;
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Fatal Error");
        System.exit(0);
        return 0; //Needed to keep the compiler happy
    }
}
```

Comment: This smells a little to me - throw an `Exception`; something else should `exit`. Preferably nothing...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd argue that this is bad design on the programmer's part, but it's simple enough and gets the job done I suppose.  Perhaps the book provides more context around this example?  Maybe they use this to make a point about the language and not to actually solve a problem?  Because this is a poor way to control the flow of logic in the application.

At *runtime* the application will end here:

```
System.exit(0);
```

But the compiler doesn't know that.  The compiler sees this function returns an `int` and demands that all code paths return a value.  Even if one of the code paths will, at runtime, exit the function in another way.  So that last code path needs to return a value:

```
return 0;
```

It can be any integer, of course.  The developer picked `0` because it's easy, but it's essentially arbitrary.  At runtime that line won't be reached.

Comment: @bmorris591: Thanks :)  I've heard of people using exceptions for control flow, but I've never heard of using application events for control flow.

Answer (score 3):

If a method returns a value, the compiler tests every possible execution path to see whether a value is returned. If this is not the case, a compile-time error is raised.

It will *not* look into the methods that are called to see if it exits the application or something. From the compiler's point of view `System.exit()` is just a method call like any other. Without the `return 0;` statement the method would not return a value for that execution path, and that is illegal. Even if it would never get executed in practice.

Answer (score 0):

better yet

```
    System.exit(0);
    throw new AssertionError("won't reach here");
```